# split '$' seperated string and insert into table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table employee with emp_id,emp_first_name,emp_last_name,emp_salary
field.

I want to create a procedure with insert records in employee table but In procedure IN parameter in '1$shubham$tathe$5000#2$vijaj$bakse&10000#3$ram$sharma$200' and i want to insert this string in employee table with row seperated by '#' and column field seperated by '$'.

```
emp_id   |  emp_first_name |  emp_last_name  |  emp_salary

1           shubham           tathe             5000
2           vijaj             bakse             10000
3           ram               sharma            200

create or replace procedure procedure_split
(
 In_string IN varchar
)

IS

Begin
...
...
...
END;
```

In_string='1$shubham$tathe$5000#2$vijaj$bakse&10000#3$ram$sharma$200'

In_string is input parameter in procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you don't need PL/SQL for that.

Table:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (emp_id number,
  3     emp_first_name varchar2(20),
  4     emp_last_name  varchar2(20),
  5     emp_salary number);

Table created.
```

Code:

```
SQL> insert into test (emp_id, emp_first_name, emp_last_name, emp_salary)
  2  with
  3  data (col) as
  4    (select '1$shubham$tathe$5000#2$vijaj$bakse$10000#3$ram$sharma$200' from dual),
  5  red as
  6    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^#]+', 1, level) val,
  7            level lvl
  8     from data
  9     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '#') + 1
 10    ),
 11  emp as
 12    (select regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 1) emp_id,
 13            regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 2) emp_first_name,
 14            regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 3) emp_last_name,
 15            regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 4) emp_salary
 16     from red
 17    )
 18  select * From emp;

3 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

    EMP_ID EMP_FIRST_NAME       EMP_LAST_NAME        EMP_SALARY
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
         1 shubham              tathe                      5000
         2 vijaj                bakse                     10000
         3 ram                  sharma                      200

SQL>
```

---

If it *has to be* a procedure, no problem either.

Procedure:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_col in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    insert into test (emp_id, emp_first_name, emp_last_name, emp_salary)
  4    with
  5    red as
  6      (select regexp_substr(par_col, '[^#]+', 1, level) val,
  7              level lvl
  8       from dual
  9       connect by level <= regexp_count(par_col, '#') + 1
 10      ),
 11    emp as
 12      (select regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 1) emp_id,
 13              regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 2) emp_first_name,
 14              regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 3) emp_last_name,
 15              regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 4) emp_salary
 16       from red
 17      )
 18    select * From emp;
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test('1$shubham$tathe$5000#2$vijaj$bakse$10000#3$ram$sharma$200');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test;

    EMP_ID EMP_FIRST_NAME       EMP_LAST_NAME        EMP_SALARY
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
         1 shubham              tathe                      5000
         2 vijaj                bakse                     10000
         3 ram                  sharma                      200

SQL>
```